# Constructor overloading or allow null?

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, constructors

Which is the preferred design to use, one constructor that allows null, or two constructors where one throws an `ArgumentNullException` on null?

## Two constructors with exception throwing

```
public class Foo
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> _bar;

    public Foo()
    {
        _bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public Foo(IDictionary<string, string> bar)
    {
        if (bar == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }
        _bar = bar;
    }
}
```

## One constructor that handles null

```
public class Foo
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> _bar;

    public Foo(IDictionary<string, string> bar = null)
    {
        if (bar == null) {
            _bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        } else {
            _bar = bar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to take over a mutable externally owned dictionary?

Comment: You can have one constructor call the other, e.g. `:this(new Dictionary<string, string>())` in the default constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use a factory method. You can state your intention (`createEmpty()`, `createWithValues()`) and expose what you expect from the caller: `createWithValues()` - null is not allowed. The constructor would then be private and only the `createWithValues()` would contain the null check or any other value check.

```
class Foo {
    private Map<String, String> bar;
    private Foo(final Map<String, String> bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
    }

    public static Foo createEmpty() {
       return new Foo(new HashMap<>());
    } 

    public static Foo createWithValue(final Map<String, String> values) {
       if (values == null) throw new YourFavoriteExceptionForThisCase();
       return new Foo(values)
    }
}
```

Simple and clean. (Sorry, code is in java)

Comment: A factory method seems like an overkill for such a simple question. I believe it would just add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: But its not wrong, and, there are several resources which would encourage factory methods - even in this case. Downvote seems a bit strong, also because its a matter of taste. But I already read that this SO is very negative and harsh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's always interesting with different views. FYI, I did not downvote. I am new to this SO, so I don't know if its harsh.

Comment: @Fred ok, I assumed so, because of your negative reaction and normally people give a small feedback why they down vote, at least this would be spirit of SO.

Comment: It is something I've raised (it applied to questions but the same applies to answers). See [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7999/73508).

Comment: I can live with a downvote if the answer is clearly wrong, like wrong code, totally wrong answer (e.g. "How to write XML?" and some one answers with "With JDBC" or something silly like that). But in this case its all opinion based and a downvote is not justified because everything is a valid solution and only taste decides. (One could include a reference to a standard work in this case, like the GoF book but I don't think it would help)

Comment: This code is pretty neat. I don't see how this is unnecessary complex. Some people simply just don't know when to use design patterns...

Comment: Factory methods that express explicit intension and private constructors just like *this example* make code so much clearer, and IMO are therefore not an overkill. Remember code is read far more times than it is written so the clearer the intension the better because you are either writing for someone else to read or maybe even "future you" to read in weeks, months or years - when you may have forgotten the context. All to often we see code that is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest interface should be provided that covers all cases that result in valid state upon construction of your object. You should also be liberal in what you accept.  Providing one constructor is always simpler than providing two, and writers of code that use this class won't be burdened with an extra decision.

If _bar is exposed in any way from the other methods/properties of your class, document your constructor with documentation comments on what the behavior is when null is passed in as the argument to your single constructor (that being that bar is empty by default if null is passed in).

Comment: **You should also be liberal in what you accept** +1 just for this. I am staggered how many seasoned devs would rather throw an exception for an unexpected null rather than try and continue gracefully. [Tony Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare) called nulls his billion dollar mistake. That might be an underestimate in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Although use of `null` to indicate a default value is a well established principal reaching back to the C / C++ roots of C#, another approach could be to borrow the concepts of the [`Option` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) (called `Maybe` in Haskell)

This will force the caller to explicitly specify whether he wants wants the default or not. This avoids the confusion about deliberately passing `null` as a bad parameter and using `null` to indicate optional:

You would then have a single constructor which covers BOTH the concerns of your "two constructors" code.

```
public Foo(Option<IDictionary<string, string>> optionalBar)
{
    if (bar == null) 
       throw ArgumentNullException();
    if (bar.HasValue) {
        _bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    } else {
        _bar = bar.Value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, C# doesn't quite flow as nicely as say a FP language, which would use pattern matching to reason over `Some<Dictionary>` and `None`.

Comment: Most `Option` types provide `.ValueOr(default)`-like method. Use that.

Comment: Good idea. I was thinking OP may be more used to the "HasValue" / "Value" semantics of `Nullable<T>`

Comment: Also, you still need to provide the parameter-less constructor. IMO having to call `Option<IDictionary<string, string>>.None` on every other invocation is not nice. And default parameter is not supported in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm for the first case.

In the second case, it promotes `null` as a valid parameter. IMO `null` should not be used to indicate absence of value. That's why `Option` types exist (as hinted by StuartLC).

Comment: This is in C# though, which afaik do not have any `Option` type.

Comment: @Fred There are tons of libraries that provide one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely blown away by either to be honest.

The first one can throw an unexpected exception and the second initialises a member variable which hasn't even been supplied as a parameter. Constructors should not yield unexpected behaviour.

I'd prefer something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> _bar;

    private IDictionary<string, string> Bar
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bar == null)
                _bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            return _bar;
        }

        set { _bar = value; }

    }

    public Foo()
    {

    }

    public Foo(IDictionary<string, string> bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

The user is free to either supply a parameter or call the parameterless constructor. And if by some oversight, the property is called without being initialised it creates one on the fly via lazy instantiation.

Comment: I'd avoid lazy initialization, unless it provides a significant performance advantage. One problem with your implementation is that it makes the class thread unsafe for multiple readers. Another issue is that you can assign `null` the the property but when you read it back, it's suddenly another value.

Comment: Read the OP again - the intention is to defend against null. Why would I possibly want null back when it was passed in error in the first place?

Comment: You should add an exception to the setter, so a caller can't set it to `null`. Otherwise you're violating the basic expectation of properties that the getter should return the value you called the setter with (or at least a value equivalent to it). IMO your code is much worse either of the OP's variants.

Comment: Like the constructor case the property would only ever be set to null in error so no exception is required (or even desirable) here. Lazy instantiation isn't *just* about performance. It is about letting the program execution flow as much as possible whenever it is safe to do so. See LINQ's default methods for similar functionality.

Comment: If by "in error" you mean "by a bug" then an exception is very much needed, so you can quickly detect the bug, instead of masking it.

Comment: No - I mean by being set to null incorrectly...

Comment: What do you mean by *incorrectly*? That sounds like a synonym of *bug* to me. Deliberately passing `null` to the constructor may be useful, but I see no reason to deliberately set the property to null with the intention of setting it to the default value.

Comment: You could handle the null in the setter too but it would add little unless it was consumed in which case it would be handled by the getter.

Comment: I noticed that I originally had the property public which probably caused a little confusion. I've correct this now...